# Javascript up/down vote comment script (server side complete)

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm a server side dev, and javascript idiot! This means I'm struggling to work out the best way of handling this very simple bit of functionality.

Basically I have a page with many text reviews on for a product. I want to be able to vote on whether the review was good or not.

The vote section at the bottom of each review looks like this:

```
<div id="voterow-'.$arrDB['id'].'">Find this review useful? <a id="comment-vote-'.$arrDB['id'].'" href="/ajax.php?a=rv&v='.$arrDB['id'].'&d=up">Yes</a> | <a id="comment-vote-'.$arrDB['id'].'" href="/ajax.php?a=rv&v='.$arrDB['id'].'&d=down">No</i></a></div>
```

The database and ajax.php script is fine and working, I just can't work out the correct way of binding something to the click event to GET the click and change the voterow-XX div to "Thank you".

Thank you in advance. I've spent 2 hours confusing myself so far, I thought I'd ask before pulling out the rest of my hair!

Comment: Can you show the JavaScript code that you have tried?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/click/ or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick

Comment: $("#comment-vote-19771").click(function() {
     $.ajax({
      type: "GET", // or GET
      url: "/ajax.php",
      data: "a=rv&v=19771&d=up",
      success: function(data){
       $(#"voterow-19771").text("Thank you for your vote");
      }
     });
     return false;
      
    });

Answer (score 0):

As this might help someone in the future

```
                $("#comment-vote-up-'.$arrDB['id'].'").click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/ajax.php",
                    data: "a=rv&v='.$arrDB['id'].'&d=up",
                    success: function(data){
                        $("#voterow-'.$arrDB['id'].'").text("Thank you for your vote")
                    }
                });
                return false;                 
            });
```